# Selection of three children from six children

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to consider the following problem (from http://vimeo.com/6790417):

> [image]

Here, the author says that a distribution of $3$ red shirts and $3$ green shirts among the $6$ children so that each children receives shirt can be described as a combination $3$ children from $6$, or $\frac{6!}{3!\cdot 3!}$, and I can't understand why it is.

In my mind this problem can be described as how many different combinations could be $3$ from $6$, and plus also how many combination would be from $3$ shirt itself $3$ shirt, which of course is just $1$, but he omitted this and says that just selection of  $3$ from $6$ is enough. Please help me to clarify it.

Comment: Please take screenshots or copy down the information yourself into the question, so that your question will still make sense if external content is removed.

Comment: it is video how can i  take screenshot?ok wait please

Comment: i dont know on video how to take screenshot

Comment: For future reference: when referring to yourself, the personal pronoun ***I*** is capitalized.

Comment: I think the author is using the fact that once you have distributed the 3 green shirts, the remaining 3 children must get the red shirts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at it this way: you have $6!$ ways of assigning 6 T-shirts to 6 children. But then, the green T-shirts are indistinguishable, so you divide by $3!$. Same thing with the red T-shirts. Which gives you the answer you are looking for.

Here is a second way to look at it: if you distribute the green T-shirts first, then the red T-shirts will have to go to the 3 remaining children. In other words, since we assume only the colour of the T-shirt matters, what you are counting is the number of ways to distribute 3 T-shirts (for example, the green ones) among 6 children.

Comment: could  you do it a little more  detailed?

Comment: @dato Is this better?

Comment: but what is number of distribution of only green shirts?let forget red one

Comment: @dato That would be 6 choose 3, i.e. $\dfrac{6!}{3!\cdot 3!}$.

Comment: only  green one?

Comment: and also here $6$ represent  number of children ,not number of shirt right?

Comment: @dato I think I understand your confusion now. Distributing one coulour is enough, since then the other coulour goes to the remaining children. Therefore, we **multiply** $\frac{6!}{3!\cdot 3!}$ by 1, we **do not add** 1. Distributing red T-shirts and distributing green T-shirts are events happening at the **same time**, and therefore we multiply the probabilities, we don't add them.

Comment: aaaaa,that is what i wanted

Comment: i have added,that was my mistake,we are adding when we are  considering  different combination,when they are independent of each other

Comment: If you prefer, there are $\binom{6}{3}$ ways of choosing who will get the red shirts, and for each of these ways there are $\binom{3}{3}$ ways of choosing who will get the greens, for a total of $\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3}$.